# How to Configure UrlRewritingNet on the server side IIS 7 Windows 7 Server

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have finished an ASP.NET web site after making tests.

I am using  UrlRewritingNet dll from http://www.urlrewriting.net/

Then I have published it in order to upload my server (Windows 7, IIS 7 installed). After typing my site's URL I get 404 - Not found error. This is because of missing or bad configuration on the server side. But I do not know what to do exactly.

Searched many times but could not find anything close to my problem.

For a last chance I am here. Can you help?

You can see my web.config content in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="urlrewritingnet" requirePermission="false" type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
    </configSections>

<system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
        </httpModules>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

        <handlers>
            <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>

            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>

            <add name="reww" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"/>

            <add name="rewwibu" path="*.ibu" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"/>
        </handlers>

        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>

    <urlrewritingnet configSource="ExternalRewrite.config"/>
</configuration>
```

This is my new Web.Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="GoAnasayfa">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/Anasayfa.ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx?lang={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="GoIletisim">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/Iletisim.ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Contact.aspx?lang={R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="GoDereceProgramlari">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/DereceProgramlari/([_0-9a-z-]+).ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="DegreePrograms.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;derece={R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="GoOgrenci">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/Ogrenci.ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Ogrenci.aspx?lang={R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="GoKatalog">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9])/Katalog.ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Catalog.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;opID={R:2}&amp;pmID={R:3}&amp;oid={R:4}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="GoDersDetay">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9])/([0-9])/DersAyrintilari.ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="CourseDetail.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;opID={R:2}&amp;pmID={R:3}&amp;DersID={R:4}&amp;dersKodu={R:5}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="GoLLPKoordinatorleri">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/LLPKoordinatorleri.ibu" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Coordinators.aspx?lang={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I type my web adress the address bar is filled with lang parameter like below:

```
http://somedomain.com/tr-TR/Anasayfa.ibu?lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr&lang=tr-tr....
```

and then browser shows an error message:

> Invalid Redirect URL

Comment: I'm not the best with regular expressions, but you should look at changing your regex from `^([_0-9a-z-]+)` to `[a-z][a-z]-[A-Z][A-Z]`. This will only allow lang in the format like `en-US` or `tr-TR` where the first two letters are lowercase and the last two letters are uppercase. You may want to ignore case so you would add an or condition to your regex to look for the lowercase a-z in addition to the uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the URL rewrite module from Microsoft?
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Be sure to install the correct version based on your system's setup. Then you can proceed with creating your rewrite rules as demonstrated here:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks. That is what I want actually. I also would like to know if I could write the rules in a .config file instead of writing in IIS on the server. Because I have an oppurtunity to configure the server this time, but in the futur I will have not. +1

Comment: I have opened my web.config and got my answer. (:

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: I clearly understand the rule writing. Now I am getting 404 error. For example: My website's openning page is http://somedomain.com/Default.aspx?lang=en-US and I rewrite it as http://somedomain.com/en-US/Home.ibu But server seeks for en-US folder.

Comment: Can you post your rewrite rule?

Comment: you may find my new web.config at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 10):

Try to add:

```
<add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
<remove name="Session"/>
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

to your **web.config** under

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ... 
    <modules>
      <!-- add here -->
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Not sure what changed and we didn't want to have to redo our site.  Thank you!!

Comment: The module entry sometimes disappears in Visual Studio when you are upgrading the .NET frameworks.